# Can anyone show me a solution to Iterate all IPv4 addresses found in a file?

Tags: rust

When I am experimenting with a new language that I'm unfamiliar with, my hello world is listing all IPv4 found in a mixed file (for example a log file). I think it is a good exercise because it gets me to practice with IO, packages, functions, regexes and iterators.

I tried for 2-3 hours to accomplish that in Rust, I still haven't found any elegant way to do it. I'm obviously doing it wrong.

Can anyone show me their solution to achieve this? It will help my brain to unlock by seeing the most efficient/elegant way. Or do you recommend me to continue to bash on the pile until I have it right?

**Passing a file name to a function, which returns iterator of all IPv4 in that file.**

I saw that Rust support iterators as well as generators/yield. I would like to see solutions for both if possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the simplicity I avoid error handling (with `unwrap` and `expect`), since it may harm readability. For that kind of task you don't need an external crates (e.g. regexes), because some parsing already implemented in standard library with [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). For the per-line reading a [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait with [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) wrapper might do the thing. And composed it becomes ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ab060f9f742538c6cdceb77eee4e1f8)):

```rust
fn iterate_over_ips(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Ipv4Addr> {
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
    io::BufReader::new(file)
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.expect("line read").parse().expect("ip invalid format"))
}
```

[Generator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Generator.html) is an unstable feature (so its API may change anytime) and for now mostly used internally by a compiler for asynchronous code. Iterators are way better for this particular task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However you made me realize I forgot to specify that the file could contain more than just IPv4s, like a log file for example. But I think that I will try the approach with a function and map instead of struct/trait/impl like I was previously doing, which was more OOP paradigm, probably overkill in that context.

Comment: Dammit I'm currently playing with it, it answers lots of questions that I had by just reading it, like how to use Iterator generics, and pass or return impl, as well as a simple map example. Many thanks !

Comment: Cool! Glad that it helped